# Scrollmagic plugin using Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to coding by vue, and I was searching for similar plugin to scrollmagic but developed by Vue not JQuery.

I have been searching from long but didn't get lucky about it yet.

thanks

Comment: Why `not jquery`? Do you have a problem connecting jquery to vue?

Comment: It doesn't look like [scrollmagic](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/index.html) is dependent on jQuery, anyway.

Comment: It's just now I'm trying to work with vue and I want to develop the home page of tht website using only Vuejs 
" https://5050climate.org/ "

but i got stuck in the part where we used scrollmagic to develop and ws searching for similar plugin

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who has a similar quesiton, for Vue projects you can use [vue-scrollmagic](https://github.com/magr0s/vue-scrollmagic) plugin